# Incorrect taxonomy ID assigned to post with custom query

Tags: wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'm having a strange issue where the output of the following query isn't always correct.

```
<?php // Get all the categories
$categories = get_terms( 'soort-event', array(
'include' => array( 36,37,44),
) );

foreach ( $categories as $category ):
    
    $meta_query = array(
                      array(
                    'key'     => 'datum_event',
                    'value'   => date('Ymd'),
                    'type'    => 'DATE',
                    'compare' => '>',
                    )
                  ); 

    $events = new WP_Query(
        array(
                'post_type'       => 'events',
                'orderby'         => 'meta_value_num',
                'order'           => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page'  => '3',  
                'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'soort-event',
                    'terms'     =>  $category,
                    'field'     => 'term_id'
                )
            ),             
                'meta_query'      => $meta_query
          )
     );
    ?>
    
<?php if ($events-> have_posts()):?>

// Display some taxonomy data

    while ($events->have_posts()) : $events->the_post(); ?>
            
       // Display some post data
    
    // End loop 
    endwhile;?>
        
    endif;
        
    // Reset things, for good measure
    wp_reset_postdata();

// end the loop
endforeach;
?>
```

When I echo `$category->term_id` within the loop it shows one of three assigned ID's as set by the query (36,37,44). However their actual taxonomy ID is something different. I checked this in the wp_terms_relationship database table.

I don't understand why this happens and only for some specific posts. I'm using the query above on a different template with only some other taxonomy ID's and the output is just fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is the output of `$category` correct in your tax_query? Does it output just an ID? Can you try to edit the terms parameter in your tax_query, like so: `'terms' =>  array($category->term_id)`

Comment: Editing the terms parameter solved the issue indeed, thanks! But I only don't understand why the previous parameter didn't work in all cases. Can you explain me why it didn't work?

Comment: Good to hear this solved your problem! The reason you had issues with this is because `get_terms` doesn't just return an ID, it returns the entire term object (unless you specify you only want to return IDs). For more information about the `get_terms` function and the possible options, you can check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone visiting this topic in the future, I will form an answer of my comment.

The reason for this issue was the use of `$category` inside the `tax_query`. The `get_terms` function return terms as entire objects by default. The `tax_query` expects an ID (or an array of IDs). This caused issues with the execution of the `tax_query`.

For anyone having the same problem, make sure your only including your term IDs. So this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'soort-event',
        'terms'     =>  $category,
        'field'     => 'term_id'
    )
)
```

Becomes this:

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'soort-event',
        'terms'     =>  array($category->term_id),
        'field'     => 'term_id'
    )
)
```

More about `get_terms`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

More about `tax_query`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters